# How to make a PDF field generate a unique number?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

We need one field in a PDF to generate a unique number for a client ID, so we were thinking if it generated the date and time down to the minute that should work.
Is it possible to have the PDF generate this on opening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

However, it may not be the very best idea to use the time when the file is opened, because it would be possible to use the same file for multiple cases (and clients). If you want to use open file, fine, but you might also add the same function to the Reset of the form.

The practical part would be with the following code:

```
var myField = this.getField("theFieldToBeFilled) ;
var now = new Date() ;
myField.value = Math.floor(now.getTime() / 1000) ;
```

and that should do it.

Note that `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since an origin date (actually, Jan. 1st, 1979, 00:00:00:000 GMT).

In order to get a shorter string, we can divide this by 1000, and get seconds; divide it by another 60, you would get minutes. And as you need an integer, round down the result of the division.